# How do I find Wyvern mutagens?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I need Wyvern mutagens for a decoction. I understand that with normally spawned wyverns they are randomly dropped, but are there any areas that there is a higher chance of receiving one, or any that are received as a part of a quest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it appears there can be possible different locations that they can be spawning from:

Their official Wikia recommends here: Around and south of Crookback Bog

One from YouTube back from 2015:

However if this has been patched out by this point is unknown (This area contains a respawning level 14 Wyvern. This spawn still functions as of patch 1.12. If you don't get a respawn fast travel away, meditate and then return.)

Attach is a picture of a location that you can potentially find some guarding treasure 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are three quests in the main game with Wyverns.

1. The Most Truest of Basilisks. Probably easiest but you have to find this quest as it is not on a notice board.
2. Patrol Gone Missing.
3. Phantom of the Trade Route. This one is hard if you aren't at a high enough level.

There are a few Wyverns outside of quests. I think they are also at the same locations.